# Passing a function and arguments to a function and purrr

Tags: r, purrr

Let's say I have the following function:

```r
new_func <- function(.data, .x, .fns, ...){
  
  # Arguments
  value_var_expr <- rlang::enquo(.x)
  func <- .fns
  func_chr <- deparse(substitute(.fns))
  passed_args <- list(...)
  
  # New Param Args ----
  # I do this because na.rm = TRUE when passed to say quantile gets
  # converted to 1 or 100%
  if ("na.rm" %in% names(passed_args)) {
    tmp_args <- passed_args[!names(passed_args) == "na.rm"]
  }
  
  if (!exists("tmp_args")) {
    args <- passed_args
  } else {
    args <- tmp_args
  }
  
  ret <- purrr::map(
    .x = dplyr::as_tibble(.data), 
    .f = ~ func(.x, unlist(args)) %>%
      purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, name = .y)) %>%
      purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble)
  ) %>%
    purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, sim_number = .y)) %>%
    purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble) %>%
    dplyr::select(sim_number, name, .x) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(.x = as.numeric(.x)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(sim_number = factor(sim_number)) %>%
    dplyr::rename(value = .x)
  
  cn <- c("sim_number", "name", func_chr)
  names(ret) <- cn
  
  return(ret)
  
}
```

Now try using `IQR` with no additional arguments passed

```r
> new_func(mtcars, mpg, IQR)
 Error in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] else if (anyNA(x)) stop("missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE") : 
argument is of length zero
```

Passing only `na.rm = TRUE`

```r
> new_func(mtcars, mpg, IQR, na.rm = TRUE)
 Error in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] else if (anyNA(x)) stop("missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE") : 
argument is of length zero
```

Passing `type = 7`

```r
> new_func(mtcars, mpg, IQR, type = 7)
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   sim_number  name    IQR
   <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 mpg            1   7.38
 2 cyl            1   4   
 3 disp           1 205.  
 4 hp             1  83.5 
 5 drat           1   0.84
 6 wt             1   1.03
 7 qsec           1   2.01
 8 vs             1   1   
 9 am             1   1   
10 gear           1   1   
11 carb           1   2
```

Now I cannot pass simply `...` like I could if I were doing say `ret <- sapply(.data, .x, ...)`

How can I correct this? I did try doing something like `dots <- rlang::enquos(...)` and then doing `func(.x, !!!dots)` which also fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to take care of the cases where `args` returns `length` 0

```
new_func <- function(.data, .x, .fns, ...){
  
  # Arguments
  value_var_expr <- rlang::enquo(.x)
  func <- .fns
  func_chr <- deparse(substitute(.fns))
  passed_args <- list(...)
  
  if(length(passed_args) > 0) {
  
  # New Param Args ----
  # I do this because na.rm = TRUE when passed to say quantile gets
  # converted to 1 or 100%
  if ("na.rm" %in% names(passed_args)) {
    tmp_args <- passed_args[!names(passed_args) == "na.rm"]
  }
  
  
  if (!exists("tmp_args")) {
    args <- passed_args
  } else {
    args <- tmp_args
  }
  } else {
     args <- NULL
  } 
  if(length(args) == 0) args <- NULL
  ret <- purrr::map(
      .x = dplyr::as_tibble(.data), 
      .f = ~ if(is.null(args)) func(.x) else func(.x, unlist(args))  %>%
        purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, name = .y)) %>%
        purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble)
    ) %>%
    purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, sim_number = .y))  %>%
     purrr::map_dfr(dplyr::as_tibble, .id = 'name') %>%
     dplyr::select(sim_number, name, `.x`) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(.x = as.numeric(.x)) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(sim_number = factor(sim_number)) %>%
       dplyr::rename(value = .x)
  
     cn <- c("sim_number", "name", func_chr)
     names(ret) <- cn
    return(ret)
}
```

-testing

```
> new_func(mtcars, mpg, IQR, na.rm = TRUE)
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   sim_number name     IQR
   <fct>      <chr>  <dbl>
 1 mpg        mpg     7.38
 2 cyl        cyl     4   
 3 disp       disp  205.  
 4 hp         hp     83.5 
 5 drat       drat    0.84
 6 wt         wt      1.03
 7 qsec       qsec    2.01
 8 vs         vs      1   
 9 am         am      1   
10 gear       gear    1   
11 carb       carb    2   
> new_func(mtcars, mpg, IQR)
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   sim_number name     IQR
   <fct>      <chr>  <dbl>
 1 mpg        mpg     7.38
 2 cyl        cyl     4   
 3 disp       disp  205.  
 4 hp         hp     83.5 
 5 drat       drat    0.84
 6 wt         wt      1.03
 7 qsec       qsec    2.01
 8 vs         vs      1   
 9 am         am      1   
10 gear       gear    1   
11 carb       carb    2   
> 
> new_func(mtcars, mpg, IQR, type = 7)
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   sim_number name     IQR
   <fct>      <chr>  <dbl>
 1 mpg        mpg     7.38
 2 cyl        cyl     4   
 3 disp       disp  205.  
 4 hp         hp     83.5 
 5 drat       drat    0.84
 6 wt         wt      1.03
 7 qsec       qsec    2.01
 8 vs         vs      1   
 9 am         am      1   
10 gear       gear    1   
11 carb       carb    2
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this completely, but I think the issue is that you're passing an empty `list` as an argument.

This might be a solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

new_func <- function(.data, .x, .fns, ...){
  
  # Arguments
  value_var_expr <- rlang::enquo(.x)
  func <- .fns
  func_chr <- deparse(substitute(.fns))
  passed_args <- list(...)
  
  
  # New Param Args ----
  # I do this because na.rm = TRUE when passed to say quantile gets
  # converted to 1 or 100%
  if ("na.rm" %in% names(passed_args)) {
    args <- passed_args[!names(passed_args) == "na.rm"]
  } else {
    args <- passed_args
  }
  
  if (length(args) < 0) {
    args <- NULL
  }
  
  ret <- purrr::map(
    .x = dplyr::as_tibble(.data), 
    .f = ~ func(.x, unlist(args)) %>%
      purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, name = .y)) %>%
      purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble)
  ) %>%
    purrr::imap(.f = ~ cbind(.x, sim_number = .y)) %>%
    purrr::map_df(dplyr::as_tibble) %>%
    dplyr::select(sim_number, name, .x) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(.x = as.numeric(.x)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(sim_number = factor(sim_number)) %>%
    dplyr::rename(value = .x)
  
  cn <- c("sim_number", "name", func_chr)
  names(ret) <- cn
  
  return(ret)
  
}

new_func(mtcars, mpg, IQR, type = 7, na.rm = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>    sim_number  name    IQR
#>    <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 mpg            1   7.38
#>  2 cyl            1   4   
#>  3 disp           1 205.  
#>  4 hp             1  83.5 
#>  5 drat           1   0.84
#>  6 wt             1   1.03
#>  7 qsec           1   2.01
#>  8 vs             1   1   
#>  9 am             1   1   
#> 10 gear           1   1   
#> 11 carb           1   2
```

Comment: ahhhhhh  args <- NULL